# Concatenate Query Results: Possible?

Tags: php, mysql

Wondering if this is how it works:

```
$result .= mysqli_query($query1);
$result .= mysqli_query($query2);
```

Would $result be the combination of queries 1 and 2?

Comment: Just try it. Instead you could use the MySQL `UNION`.

Comment: You can fetch them into array then merge

Answer (score 1):

No, because you have to *fetch* the results from `mysqli_query`.  That function will only return the result resource.

The `fetch` results are usually not a string either but rather an array or object.  This means that concatenation *still* wouldn't work.  You may do something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$value .= $row['selectedValue'];
$result = mysqli_query($query2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$value .= $row['otherSelectedValue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selected the same fields in both queries you can do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query1." union ".$query2);
```

Comment: That should work if there is no semicolon on the end of the value of $query1